# Retrieve data from a HTTP get request

Tags: java, jquery, get

How do I access the parameters sent in a jQuery `$.get` request?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var input1 =  "name has been sent";
    $("#btn1").click(function(){
        $.get("http://localhost:8080/RestHelloWorld/rest/message/hello",  {
            name: input1     
        });
    });
```

Java:

```
@GET
@Path("/hello")
public String printMessage(@FormParam("name") String n){
    System.out.println(n);
    return "helloWorld";
}
```

The connection is fine as I am printing `null` to the console. How do I access the data sent within the HTTP request? I'm thinking the `@FormParam` is not the correct way to reference the data.

Answer (score 0):

Found the correct command - (@QueryParam instead of (@FormParam

```
@GET
@Path("/hello")
public String printMessage(@QueryParam("name") String n){
    System.out.println(n);
    return "helloWorld number 2";

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@RequestParam` for parameters;

```
@GET
@Path("/hello")
public String printMessage(@RequestParam("name") String n){
    System.out.println(n);
    return "helloWorld";
}
```

Or `HttpServletRequest`;

```
@GET
@Path("/hello")
public String printMessage(HttpServletRequest request){
    System.out.println(request.getParameter("name"));
    return "helloWorld";
}
```